# reverse string without using strrev and any type of loop or recursion

Tags: php

I want to reverse string using substr function and without using strrev and any type of loop (not recursion too). other functions can be used to do this task.

Like: Anshul reverse: luhsnA

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this?

Comment: i've used looping system but its not in the criterea

Comment: Why do you have to follow those criteria? Is it not enough to solve the problem? Built in functions were made to make life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why those conditions have to be followed but this should work -

```
$str = 'abcd';
// convert to array
$arr = str_split($str);
// sort by keys in descending order
krsort($arr);
// concatenate the careaters
echo implode('', $arr);
```

Comment: thanks very much its working...!